# Unable to resolve System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation after adding Microsoft.AspNetCore package

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

I have encountered the following problem.

I have created a new lib project targeting .net framework 4.6.2
and referenced System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation package via NuGet. (The Object Browser is displaying that that dll has version 4.0.1.0, (in nuget i pointed to instal ver 4.3))

I reload the project, to check if there are no problems with references.

Now I install Microsoft.AspNetCore, I reload the project, and the reference to 
System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation and System.Net.Htpp are gone.

[image]

ps. installing .netstandard package did not help.

Does anyone had a similar problem ?

Comment: Please include the actual warning from the output window (as text). A screenshot of warning icons is not particularly useful.

Comment: Which version of visual studio are you using?

Comment: @MartinUllrich vs 2017 15.3.3

Comment: @MartinUllrich I only found this:
Warning  The referenced component 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation' could not be found. ClassLibrary1

Comment: question has been retargeted more broadly on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48520188/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-runtime-interopservices-runtimeinformati

Answer (score 7):

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation` the lowest support .net framework version is `4.7.1`. You can see the detail in [System.Runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.runtimeinformation?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 3):

In my case adding

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
  <GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

to the csproj file helped.
I'm still getting missing references, but while running the project I do not get any missing file exceptions

Comment: This may be related to a Visual Studio update, more info here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/95070/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-systemruntime-vers.html

Comment: I had an issue using OpenCvSharp with .NET 4.6.2 throwing `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation, Version=0.0.0.0` and this fixed it. Thank you!

Comment: @p3tch I have the same problem with OpenCvSharp but I can't fix it, do you have some clue?

Comment: @jæk have you added System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation from nuget? If not, try that